# Page doesn't scroll when select2 is used in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, dropdown

0

I am new to sharepoint and using sharepoint 2016, in which I want to use select2 jquery plugin for dropdown list. Since sharepoint is a cms, I can't give specific class and id to the select field. so, I have used select2 for all the select field. Then when page is reloaded/refreshed it works and if I choose any one select field then page stops scrolling.

I have added script to the page. For testing purpose I have not saved the scripts locally. The code is below.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').select2();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you adding this script on SharePoint OOTB forms ?

Comment: I embed the this script in script editor